# How to set background color in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

The background color of my scene is black. How can I change this color?

Looks like I'm doing something wrong because `glClearColor()` function is not working: I tried to change the values but nothing happened. I'm new to `OpenGL` and programming in general.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
void Ayarlar(void);
void CizimFonksiyonu(void);
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    glutInit(&argc, argv);


    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB); 
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200); 
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutCreateWindow("ilk OpenGL programim");
    glutDisplayFunc(CizimFonksiyonu);
    glutMainLoop();
    Ayarlar();


    return 0;
}
void Ayarlar(void) {

    glClearColor(1 ,0 ,0 , 1); 
    glShadeModel(GLU_FLAT);

}
void CizimFonksiyonu(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush(); 

}
```

[image: snapshot of sample]

Comment: `glClearColor()` is first part of the story. It defines the clear colors and need to be called only if the clear color shall be changed. `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` is the one which does the actual clear (with the current clear color). It should be called e.g. at the beginning of every rendering step.

Comment: Looking twice at your source (sorry, I struggled a bit with the non-English function names), I realized that you call `glClearColor()` too late. Do it before `glutMainLoop()` to make it effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ayarlar()` has to be called be for [`glutMainLoop()`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node14.html). `glutMainLoop` enters the GLUT event processing loop and never returns. You have to set the OpenGL states before.

```cpp
glutDisplayFunc(CizimFonksiyonu);

Ayarlar();
glutMainLoop();
```